# How to change the toolbars' (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) menu onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, customization, toolbar

I have a toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) on an activity which displays a navigation and a menu icon (three dots vertically). When I switch to a certain fragment, I am displaying a "check icon" instead of the menu icon on the right side by calling toolbar.setOverflowIcon.

Now I want to change the onclick function of the menu icon so it displays another fragment instead of opening the dropdown menu.

I tried to find a function which would be called something like "setOnMenuClickListener" to handle the click on the menu icon, but I only found "onMenu**Item**ClickListener" which is not what I want.

This is my toolbar and the navigation drawer:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

This is the function to change the toolbar icon and its onClickListener:

```
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_white));
```

pseudo code(because there is no such function):

```
toolbar.setOnMenuClickListener(new Listener {
display the fragment
}
```

I appreciate your help, if you have further questions to my problem do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Creating custom toolbar is best solution for your scenario.and based on current fragment you can make changes to icon in toolbar.

Comment: so how do i change the onmenuclicklistener then?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36766820/6587502

Comment: This is just providing the navigation(on the left side) click, no the menu (one the right side) click

Comment: Checkout this link after doing that we don't have to use onmenuclicklistener just create onClick listner of menuicon ImageView like we do for other button in screen.
And You can directly one and close Drawer using   `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`          
 
https://sourcey.com/articles/android-custom-centered-actionbar-with-material-design